# what's the shortcut for create comments @return and @param in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, comments, keyboard-shortcuts

whats the shortcut for comment @param and @return in IntelliJ?
like following code:

```
    /**
     * Run the sql query provided and return ResultSet object
     * @param sql the query to run
     * @return ResultSet object  that contains data
     */
    public static ResultSet runQuery(String sql){

        try {
            stm = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            rs = stm.executeQuery(sql); // setting the value of ResultSet object
            rsmd = rs.getMetaData() ;  // setting the value of ResultSetMetaData for reuse
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("ERROR OCCURRED WHILE RUNNING QUERY "+ e.getMessage() );
        }

        return rs ;

    }
```

Comment: In my experience they appear when you type `/**[enter]` above a method definition.

Comment: so, after /**[press enter] then manual to add @param and @return? 
any shortcut to create it?